# Dnsleaktest.com fails to function/does not find the DNS servers when I use a proxy. Why?

Tags: vpn, proxy, dns, firefox

When I use a VPN, and when I go to the website dnsleaktest.com, it displays the DNS servers of the VPN service provider, and not any DNS server of my ISP.
So far so good.

However, I am puzzled when without the VPN turned on, if I go to a popular proxy site, for example proxfree.com *and then* go to dnsleaktest.com, while the test notes the proxy IP address and not the one allotted by my ISP, *it nevertheless fails to load the DNS servers list of proxfree.com.*

Why would this happen, and can you guys replicate this and tell me if this happens to you as well?
I am using firefox and chrome, both have flash and javascript enabled, so that cannot be a reason for the test not working.
I dont know what is breaking/IF anything is breaking at all on the side of proxfree.com or dnsleaktest.com.

But it's not just proxfree.com. 
I have tried this with https://hide.me/en/proxy and http://www.cyberghostvpn.com/en_us/proxy and even hidemyass.com/proxy
and the dnsleaktest.com **'standard' or 'extended test' refuses to load**.

I am not sure what is happening, and if this means that something is being broken midway in the connection and thus if it is a security issue or not.
Any help in understanding this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Proxying is for HTTP(S) (application layer) and does not affect your DNS configuration, while a VPN pipes all outbound traffic (including DNS) through the VPN. Anything that's not configured to use the proxy will proceed from your computer as normal.

Comment: This is misleading.  Do you think that web requests made through the proxy are specified as hostnames or IP addresses?  If hostnames, why would your workstation need to do a DNS lookup, and how can the proxy avoid doing a lookup?

Comment: My statement is still correct, but you bring up some clarity I missed. The proxy will ultimately need to do the DNS lookup, but somehow the user's computer isn't performing the JavaScript requests through the proxy or something. Unlike a VPN, there is nothing preventing it from doing DNS lookups normally.